# How to keep the hover when your mouse is not hover, Jquery

Tags: jquery, hover

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/XYbmE/75/

I want the `div#first` to stay blue if the black box is there. The black box only appear if i click on the `div#first`. If i click anywhere else the blackbox should be hidden and the `div#first` should be back red.

What should i do?

Comment: Are you asking also how to hide the black box and remove the color once you click somewhere else?  The hiding of the black box does not exist in your current code.

Comment: Yes i didn't write is since i don't know how to do it ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a job for classes!

When the click event is triggered, add a class to `#first` that has the same CSS as `:hover`.

```
div#first:hover,div#first.hover{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background-color:blue;
}
```

And then, add the class on click:

```
$('#first').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
  $('#second').show();
});
```

Remove the class and black box, when you click elsewhere:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('#first')){
        $('#first').removeClass('hover');
        $('#second').hide();
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/EjKKP/

Comment: You beet me to the answer. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pdja/1/) code update.

Comment: What should i do if i don't want to lose the black box when i click on it, since i got link in it

Comment: Nvm, if i got link in it, it will change page so it's ok! Thanks :)!

Comment: @CharlesLemarier: Edit the `body` click event to not trigger on that either.  Or take at look at the other answers.  `e.stopPropagation();` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an update jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XYbmE/87/

**JS**

```
// This will take care of restoring the boxes
// when user clicks outside the boxes
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#first').removeClass('active');
    $('#second').hide();
});

// This will add an "active" class and prevent
// the above code from being triggered when
// the box is clicked.
$('#first').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#second').show();
});
```

**CSS**

```
/* Have #first.active:hover look/behave the same as #first */
div#first:hover, div#first.active {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: In your jsFiddle the box doesn't stay blue when the black box is open. OP said "I want the div#first to stay blue if the black box is there."

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, For 2nd Question, you need to add a small script on document.click to hide and remove class.

```
$('#first').click(function(e) {
 $(this).addClass('hover');
 $('#second').show();

 //stop bubbling
 e.stopPropagation();

});

$(document).click (function (e) {
   if (this.id == 'first') {
      return;
  }
  $('#first').removeClass('hover');
  $('#second').hide();
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/4pdja/3/)** here